# Why doesn't my jQuery work for elements loaded via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page which contains a form with the following elements:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="CadsInsertion" method="POST">
    <div id="formItems" class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date"><label class="btn btn-danger" id="_date">-</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

As the page is loaded I use the following jQuery to add more elements which are fetched from my Servlet `FormElements`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "FormElements",
        data: {docType: "<%=session.getAttribute("docType")%>"},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data != null) {
                $("#formItems").append(data);
            }
    }});
});
```

What I basically do in the servlet is process the data from the ajax call and write some jsp elements accordingly. For the sake of simplicity I shall omit the Servlet implementation and just skip to the output.

After the ajax code is executed, new elements are added into the `formItems` division:

```
<input id="Image" type="text" placeholder="Image" name="Image">
<label id="_Image" class="btn btn-danger">-</label>
<br>
<input id="Format" type="text" placeholder="Format" name="Format">
<label id="_Format" class="btn btn-danger">-</label>
<br>
<input id="Type" type="text" placeholder="Type" name="Type">
<label id="_Type" class="btn btn-danger">-</label>
```

Now my question is, I use the following jQuery to remove elements from the form:

```
$("label").click(function(e) {
    var item = e.target.id;
    item = item.replace("_", "");
    $("#" + item).remove();
    e.target.remove();
});
```

But this only works for the elements which were already statically defined in my page and does not work for the elements loaded using ajax. Why is this?

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegating](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$("#formItems").on('click', 'label', function(e) {
   var item = e.target.id;
   item = item.replace("_", "");
   $("#" + item).remove();
   e.target.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have appended the element you need to rebind the handlers to it or use jQuery's on() function.

You need to [delegate the event](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events) to the closest static ancestor element within the page (see also "[Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)"). This simply means, the element where you bind your event handler must already exist at the time the handler is bound, so for dynamically generated elements you must allow the event to bubble up and handle it further up.

use this

```
 // instead of document you can use any parent element selector which is static(does not appended)
 $(document).on("click","label",(function(e) {
        var item = e.target.id;
        item = item.replace("_", "");
        $("#" + item).remove();
        e.target.remove();
    });
```

Comment: Because when your code execute there is no element to bind event upon, So you have to bind event on whole document and add filter to it.

Comment: In our case you don't need use `document`, it does not make sense, you can use as parent `#formItems` because this item originally there on the page...

Comment: yes you are right i have mention in comment that one can use any parent element which are exist on page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".form-inline").on('click', 'label', function(e) {
   var item = e.target.id;
   item = item.replace("_", "");
    $("#" + item).remove();
    e.target.remove();
 });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.